# Cell appears blank in the UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am making a view controller with `tableView` for presenting individual news cards.  I want to load cells once and for all (without reusing it as usual). So I do this:

```
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "RatingNewsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "RatingNewsCell")
    tableView.register(UINib(nibName: "PromoNewsCell", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "PromoNewsCell")

    var cells = [UITableViewCell]()

    let rating = RatingNewsCell()
    rating.delegate = self
    cells.append(rating)

    etc...

    self.items = cells
```

Cells are loaded like this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    return items[indexPath.section]
}
```

Cell code looks like this:

```
class RatingNewsCell: UITableViewCell
{
    var delegate: RatingNewsCellDelegate?

    @IBOutlet weak var shopNameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var bouquetImageView: RoundImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var floristImageView: RoundImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingPicker!

    override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?)
    {
        super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: "RatingNewsCell")
    }

    required init?(coder decoder: NSCoder)
    {
        super.init(coder: decoder)
    }

    override func awakeFromNib()
    {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        ratingControl.setSelected(newIndex: 0)
    }
}
```

In the result I've got a table view, but cell just appears blank:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Why not use proper cell reuse?

Comment: Did you really mean to use indexPath.section?

Comment: @kailoon yes, I use sections instead of cells to make easy offsets between cells :D

Answer (score 1):

I suggest to refactor your code to use tableView's datasource method though you are only using static cells.

```
enum Section: Int {
    case RatingNews
    case PromoNews
    static var count: Int { return Section.PromoNews.rawValue + 1 }
}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return Section.count
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let section = Section(rawValue: indexPath.section)!
    switch section {
    case .PromoNews:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "RatingNewsCell", for: indexPath) as! RatingNewsCell
        return cell
    case .RatingNews:
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "PromoNewsCell", for: indexPath) as! PromoNewsCell
        return cell
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to call

```
tableView.delegate = self
```

and

```
tableView.dataSource = self
```

Comment: These lines are present in the code. Otherwise tableView would have been empty